# Highly isolated two different reservoir

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy, time

Lets say we have highly isolated two different reservoir.One is cold the other one is hot.We just connected them with a tube.(Which is also isolated) Tube has "0" thermal conductivity.
If we let system, as time goes infinity, Can we expect at the some point tube lost its thermal unconductivity(due to aging) and starts to exchange heat between reservoirs till the hit maximum entropy stage?

I mean,Does 2nd law either way unavoidable?

Comment: Nothing physical  has exactly zero conductivity, not even the walls of the reservoirs.

Comment: What does "til the hit maximum entropy stage" mean?  And what does "Does 2nd law either way unavoidable" mean?

Answer (score 0):

The problem with this hypothetical scenario is that there's no such tube in real world and, even if it did, it would certainly not violate the Second Law of Thermodynamics. It's always valid on macroscopic scale. See Maxwell's demon for an example where it might hypothetically be violated on microscopic scale.